# Cómo convertir un array de objetos en un solo objeto que tenga de propiedades los nombres de los objetos del array en javascript

Tags: javascript

Estoy usando JavaScript y al hacer una petición, esta me retorna un `array` de objetos que luce así:

```
[
    {
        "id": 32,
        "nombre": "mexico",
        "coordenadas_lon": "98523",
        "coordenadas_lat": "9513",
    },
    {
        "id": 33,
        "nombre": "colombia",
        "coordenadas_lon": "89413",
        "coordenadas_lat": "85123",
    }
]
```

Quisiera crear un objeto con solo los nombres y el `id` de los países de ese arreglo de la siguiente forma:

```
{
    32 : 'mexico',
    33 : 'colombia'
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yo lo haria de la siguiente manera:
Primero obtengo la variable con el objeto inicial:

```
var a = [
    {
        "id": 32,
        "nombre": "mexico",
        "coordenadas_lon": "98523",
        "coordenadas_lat": "9513",
    },
    {
        "id": 33,
        "nombre": "colombia",
        "coordenadas_lon": "89413",
        "coordenadas_lat": "85123",

    }   
]
```

Luego 
Declaro una variable para el nuevo objeto

```
var b = new Object()
```

Entonces procedo a recorrer mi objeto iniciar, de la siguiente manera:

```
$.each(a,function(index,val){
    var z; //Declaro una variable temporal de cada vuelta del ciclo
    z = val.id; //lleno la variable con el id, que ahora sera mi indice
    b[z] = val.nombre; // asigno al objeto final con el indice, el valor correspondiente
})
```

Finalmente ya tengo mi Objeto nuevo:

```
{ 
    32: "mexico", 
    33: "colombia"
}
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, sin embargo en el sitio evitamos responder preguntas tipo: *necesito "esto", por favor que alguien lo haga por mi*. Cuando la persona que hace la pregunta no ha mostrado su código o explicado bien su dificultad, se le invita a hacerlo para poder ayudarle. Igual tu respuesta es válida. Esto sólo es una recomendación. Saludos

Answer (score 2):

```
var data = [
    {
        "id": 32,
        "nombre": "mexico",
        "coordenadas_lon": "98523",
        "coordenadas_lat": "9513",
    },
    {
        "id": 33,
        "nombre": "colombia",
        "coordenadas_lon": "89413",
        "coordenadas_lat": "85123",
    }
]

console.log( data.map(i => { return { [i.id]: i.nombre } }) )
```